# 'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs

Tags: django, authentication

i'm trying to login using django.contrib.auth but seems this does not work in Django 1.5
this is urls.py

```
r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',  {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
```

and this my template

```
1   {% extends "website/base.html" %}
2   
3   {% block content %}
4   
5   {% if form.errors %}
6   <p>Authentication error</p>
7   {% endif %}
8   
9   <form action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}" method="post">
10    {% for field in form %}
11    <p>
12      {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
13      {{ field.errors }}
14    </p>
15    {% endfor %}
16    <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
17    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
18  </form>
```

how can i fix it ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want quotes around the view name:

```
<form action="{% url "django.contrib.auth.views.login" %}" method="post">
```