# python 2.7 DeprecationWarnings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have recently upgraded to python 2.7.5 from 2.5
I have a software. And in order for it to run on 2.7.5, I had to fix import issues but after that, it runs fine.

But when I turned on DeprecationWarnings via `python -Wd` it gave me bunch of syntax error.
When I dont specify -Wd, it runs without any problems since it ignores those error.

Is it better to fix those error raised by -Wd or..
just leave it since it works fine as long as the warnings aren't turned on?

Pros/Cons for both approach please.

---

"A policy decision was made to silence warnings only of interest to developers. DeprecationWarning and its descendants are now ignored unless otherwise requested, preventing users from seeing warnings triggered by an application. This change was also made in the branch that will become Python 3.2. (Discussed on stdlib-sig and carried out in issue 7319.)" http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html

If they wanted devs to fix those issues, they would not have made a decision to suppress those warnings as default, correct?

Comment: Pros: you fix your code. Cons: you have to spend the time to fix your code.

Comment: @millimoose but why fix my code when I dont have to? what is the benefit of that?

Comment: If you fix your code, it won't slowly become obsolete as time passes. If you're the only person who uses your code, it might be fine, but if anybody else wants to run it, they might appreciate having code which is more up-to-date and doesn't throw warnings.

Comment: "If they wanted devs to fix those issues, they would not have made a decision to suppress those warnings as default, correct?"  I think that's exactly backwards.  *Developers* should fix those issues.  They chose to suppress ones that *users* can't do anything about, because for them it was simply noise.

Comment: @Michael0x2a it will only throw warnings if i tell it to with -Wd. If the consensus is not to run with -Wd, then i am okay, right?

Comment: @DSM not really. if it was raised by default, then devs are "forced" to fix thoes issues because users cant use it.... With suppressed as default, there would be ppl like me contemplating "why do i have to fix it if it runs fine"?

Comment: I just playing the devil's advocate here and trying to understand.

Comment: @ealeon -- eh, well, I've always had a personal philosophy of treating warnings like errors. It might not be a problem now, but warnings are a way for to the interpreter/devs to tell me that something isn't quite right. So just from that perspective, I'd fix it, to remove the possibility that there'd be any issue whatsoever either now or in the future.

Comment: @ealeon: Yes, really.  Say you release a piece of code into the world, for Python 3.3.  Afterwards, Python 3.4 introduces a DeprecationWarning for a piece of syntax you used.  If it gives a warning by default, then Python 3.4 users see a bunch of noise and they can't fix it.  If it gives an error, they can't run your code.  This way, you *as a developer* know with -Wd, and can fix it, extending the window when the code -- which still works -- will work for users noise-free.  You should still fix your code, you simply have more time to do so this way.

Comment: @DSM yes i am definitely going to fix it. I just wanted to be "convinced" to fix rather than just because i have to. Thats why I was playing devil's advocate and fishing for good reasons as to why I should fix it.

Comment: @ealeon ...Is that really the best use of everyone's time? It's your code, do what the heck you want with it.

Comment: @millimoose i was trying to see if there were any rules of thumb on this.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecation means that things are becoming out of date. i.e. sometime in the near future those models\functions\whatever are going to stop existing and (usually) be replaced by a newer and better version.

More often than not, when the developers want to get rid of some old function, they either change it at once and add helpful error messages ([like how django did in 1.5 with the urls block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974905/url-requires-a-non-empty-first-argument-the-syntax-changed-in-django-1-5-see)) or, if they can, they ease it in. i.e they leave the deprecated functions working and add warnings to tell you about them. When the next version comes out, support for those outdated functions will stop.

So for now your code will work. But if you plan to keep updating, then eventually it will stop working. It really depends on what you plan to do with the code and who uses it and so on.